# When opening jQuery dialog the page scrolls

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have rows of elements with a edit button that shows on hover. I'm trying to open my jQuery dialog window next to the element that you click on the edit button:

So far so good.

Here's my problem: the dialog opens at the right place, **but** the page scrolls down at the same time I open the dialog.

jQuery dialog code:

```
$("#object-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Save: function () {
            alert("hello");
        },
        Abort: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    show: "slow"
});
```

Initializing code for dialog and sets the dialogs position:

```
$(".matrix-cell-options-edit").click(function () {
    $("#object-form").dialog("open");
    var target = $(this).parent().parent();
    $("#object-form").dialog("widget").position({
        my: 'left bottom',
        at: 'right top',
        of: target
    });
});
```

Comment: Does the scroll still occur when you put the `dialog("open")` after the setting the position?

Comment: Yes unfortunately it does.

Comment: this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777408/window-scrolling-up-when-jquery-dialog-opens-up may prove helpful

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Im pretty sure now that my problem has to do with CSS positioning (absolute/relative). I tried this example [link](http://jsbin.com/okosi4/1/edit) that had the same problem when I used it on my own dialog. I will have to dig deeper when none of the examples in that thread worked for me. Now sure where to start though as I'm no pro at CSS. I would up your comment if i could/knew how. @Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed this. It had nothing to do with CSS. It was some discrete error that always was present. For some reason the body tag ended up before the head tag. It got nested. See this screenshot to see how it looks like in the element inspector in Chrome (not mine but similar): http://www.flickr.com/photos/57553101@N06/5357885472/

In below thread this problem was solved for some with UTF-8 without BOM but not for me. I had included db.php and a couple of other functions before the first HTML tag. I moved this down to the beginning of the body and now everything seems to work as it should!

Useful threads on this matter:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/header-appearing-in-body-tag
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/head-scriptslinks-showing-up-inside-body-tag

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. Fixed by adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` before `<html>` tag